# Designing interactive map of botanical garden in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, database, species

Using QGIS is absolutely new to me but I hope, we can make it as short and easy as possible to put my idea into practice. I hope that QGIS is the appropriate program for this purpose.

I have COREL-drawn (Coral Draw X6) map of a botanical garden, saved as SVG, which I need for my research. My intention is, to build up an interactive map/database, incorporating all my important species and their localities in the garden. And I was said, that the whole request is too long, so I'll start with the first step:

How can I import my map (as .svg or another format), that it keeps looking like it does in Corel? I found some tutorial which says to export the map as .DXF from Corel and then import this into QGIS, but the result looks pritty weird.

[image: Original Corel View]

[image: QGIS View imported as DXF]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its focussed Q&A format. Unfortunately, we are not able to provide personal tuition in using GIS software.  I recommend that you start using QGIS and when you get stuck describe what you want to do in that step, what precisely you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try importing it as a raster directly from the svg format? If that doesn't work, try converting it to another type of image file, such as jpg or pdf. You should be able to import either of those using the "Add Raster Layer" button on the Layer toolbar.

Once the image is imported into QGIS, you should georeference it so that any additional data you add will correspond to real-world coordinates. When you georeference an image, you tell QGIS the real-world coordinate of points on the image. You can use google maps to find latitude and longitude of any point.

Go to Plugin menu, Manage and Install plugins, find and install the plugin called Georeferencer GDAL. There are many sources on the internet that teach you how to use this plugin so I won't rehash them here. One good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html). Also try lesson 14.2 of the [QGIS Training Manual](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html) available from qgis.com

Comment: Links can change or disappear over time.  Please [edit] your answer to include the steps required, keeping the link as a reference instead of as the answer